# Laravel facebook login SSL certificate cURL issue

Tags: php, facebook, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I'm using socialite to authenticate users by facebook. I'm getting this error message:

```
RequestException in CurlFactory.php line 169:  
cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

I changed `php.ini` to add `.pem` file, but it still hasn't resolved the issue:

```
curl.cainfo = C:\wamp\bin\php\cacert.pem
```

Comment: How did you add the .pem file, where did you get it from?

Comment: Try downloading the current CA cert the PHP SDK contains, https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/tree/5.0-dev/src/Facebook/HttpClients/certs

Comment: How can I echo out curl.cainfo value from laravel?